# Button click background image bigger animation and load new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, odoo-website

On a site's blog section there is a nice effect for opening new blogs.

On the blogpost, there is a link to next blogpost at the bottom. If you click on the read more button the background gets bigger and automatically loads the content of that blog post. Example can be found here -

https://www.odoo.com/blog/odoo-news-5/post/odoo-10-released-337

[image]

How to implement this effect?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the a link as **READ MORE** and write a route and controller to open the current blog with that link.
eg:
in view:

```
<a t-att-href="'/blog/custom?id='+blog.id"/>
<!-- give proper style to display as a button -->
```

in controller

```
@http.route('/blog/custom', csrf=False, type="http", methods=['POST', 'GET'], auth="public", website=True)
def custom_blog(self, **kw):
    data = request.env['blog.blog'].browse(kw and kw.get('id'))
    return request.render('your_template', {'data':data }) #use dict key as per your custom template
```